# get image path from activity1 (that contain listview of picture) to activity2 (that contain canvas to draw picture returned from activity1 )

Tags: android, android-intent

I developed an activity that contains canvas to draw image and I have a menu that calla activity (this activity shows list of picture). Once I choose a picture from list, this picture must be drawn on canvas. So, my problem is how to send this picture from listView in *Activity1* to canvas on *Activity2*.

This is my code:

Activity1

```
case R.id.menu_prefs:
        Intent i = new Intent(TpMainActivity.this, ListViewImagesActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
```

Acitvity2 (list view picture)

```
public class ListViewImagesActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private PaintView paintView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    //  @Override
                    public void run() {
                    try {
                        InputStream bitmap=getAssets().open("a.gif");
                        Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
                        paintView.setBitmap(bit);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                    };
                    thread.start();

        }  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have activity1 call startActivityForResult rather than startActivity.  Then you can return a result when finish is called on activity2.  Activity1 will need to implement onActivityResult.  Activity 2 can return the path in the intent that is sent back to activity1.